# Zend Framework 1 .htaccess with subdirectory and without RewriteBase

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, url-rewriting

This is the `.htaccess` [Zend Framework 1 manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/project-structure.rewrite.html) suggests to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I intend to publish the website into a subfolder, like so: `http://localhost/my-app/` So the way to go would be to add this line to the file:

```
RewriteBase /my-app
```

Now everything works.

The problem is the subfolder name will vary (and may even be empty -> http://my-app.com/), and I would like to have a `.htaccess` file that works in every situation because I have an automated deployment procedure.

**So is there a solution for the rewriting to work without specifying `RewriteBase`?**

---

Edit: Directory structure

```
my-app/
    application/
    library/
    public/
        .htaccess
        index.php
        ...
    tests/
```

Comment: where the .htaccess located? `http://localhost/.htaccess` or `http://localhost/my-app/.htaccess`

Comment: @silentboy The .htaccess is in the `public` folder. The Apache alias points to the public folder, so `http://localhost/my-app/` points to my `public` folder.

Comment: `RewriteBase /` should help. you should add directory structure if it not solve. actually the problem isn't too big, but i have to know first branch of the my-app tree

Comment: @silentboy I edited the question with the directory structure. Note that I am trying to get rid of `RewriteBase`!

Answer (score 0):

and the public `.htaccess` should be  no `RewriteBase`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, but there is no reason for it to work. The apache alias points to the `public/` directory, not the `my-app` directory.

Comment: With this configuration this doesn't work. I end up with a 404 "The requested URL /my-app/inventory/project/ was not found on this server." and in the Apache error log: "File does not exist: D:/matthieu/my-app/public/inventory, referer: http://localhost/my-app/index/welcome"